# User Data Not Written to Firestore After Successful Firebase Auth Signup in Flutter, No Errors Shown

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 932;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 430;
    final emailController = TextEditingController();
    final passwordController = TextEditingController();
    final phoneController = TextEditingController();
    final dobController = TextEditingController();
    var selectedGender = 'None';
    void updateGender(String gender) {
      selectedGender = gender;
    }

    Future<void> signUp(BuildContext context, String gender) async {
      try {
        // Create user with email and password
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text,
        );

        final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        CollectionReference ref = firestore.collection('users');
        final data = <String, String>{
          'email': emailController.text,
          'phone': phoneController.text,
          'dob': dobController.text,
          'gender': gender,
        };
        print(userCredential.user!.uid);
        try {
          await ref
              .doc(userCredential.user!.uid)
              .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true))
              .then((value) => print(
                  "User data added to Firestore")); // Add user data to Firestore
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error adding user data to Firestore: $e");
        }

        // Show success message or navigate to another page
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Sign Up Successful')));
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        // Handle errors (e.g., email already in use)
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Error: ${e.message}')));
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        // Handle other exceptions
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Error: $e')));
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
          .primaryColor, // Set your background color in main.dart
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 24.0 * w, right: 24.0 * w, top: 40.0 * h, bottom: 24.0 * h),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Sign Up',
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.displayLarge),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),
                Image.asset(
                  'lib/images/image_2-removebg-preview.png',
                  height: 235 * h,
                  width: 319 * w,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),

                // Email Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25 * w),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'E-mail',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),

                // Password Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25 * w),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),

                // Email Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25 * w),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Phone Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),

                // Password Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25 * w),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: dobController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Date of Birth',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15 * h),
                Text(
                  "Gender",
                  style:
                      Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 24 * w,
                          ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15 * h),
                GenderSelectionWidget(
                    onGenderChanged: updateGender, w: w, h: h),
                SizedBox(height: 20 * h),
                // Login Button
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.green,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    minimumSize: Size(207 * w, 66 * h), // Text color
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => signUp(context, selectedGender),
                  child: Text('Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontSize: 32 * w)),
                ),

                // Sign Up and Forgot Password links
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GenderSelectionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double w;
  final double h;
  final Function(String) onGenderChanged;

  const GenderSelectionWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.w,
    required this.h,
    required this.onGenderChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GenderSelectionWidgetState createState() => _GenderSelectionWidgetState();
}

class _GenderSelectionWidgetState extends State<GenderSelectionWidget> {
  // Initial value is 'None'
  var selectedGender = 'None';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        _genderButton('Male', widget.w, widget.h),
        SizedBox(width: 20 * widget.w),
        _genderButton('Female', widget.w, widget.h),
        SizedBox(width: 20 * widget.w),
        _genderButton('Other', widget.w, widget.h),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _genderButton(String gender, double w, double h) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor:
            selectedGender == gender ? Colors.white : Colors.greenAccent,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        backgroundColor: selectedGender == gender
            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 157, 29)
            : Colors.white,
        minimumSize: Size(98 * w, 43 * h),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedGender = gender;
          widget.onGenderChanged(selectedGender);
        });
        // Implement your logic here
      },
      child: Text(gender,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: selectedGender == gender
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              fontSize: 24 * w)),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my signup page code where the user is successfully written to Firebase Authentication, but Firestore does not store the user data. The process seems to stall after the authentication step, with no errors shown in the console or feedback on why Firestore isn't being updated. I've confirmed that the user is created in Firebase Auth, and I've attempted to troubleshoot by checking Firestore rules and ensuring they allow write access. Additionally, I've tried adding print statements to confirm the flow of the code reaches the Firestore write operation, but it seems like the operation either doesn't execute or fails silently. I'm seeking advice on potential reasons for this issue and how to debug it, as I'm currently stuck without any error messages to guide the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Did you already step through the `signUp` code in a debugger. That's usually the best first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: yes I already did..

Comment: OK, so what was the result of that? Did you check the value of each variable on each line? And if so, what was the first line where a value dind't mean your expectation? ---  In general, keep in mind that "does not store the user data", "seems to stall" and "no errors shown" are hard to help with. Instead tell us something like, "when stepping through `signUp` in the debugger, I noticed that on line `code sample` the value of `variable` was `A`, while I expected it to be `B`". Or someting along those lines.

Comment: I fixed the issue; it was due to a VPN setting that I had set up a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue; it was due to a VPN setting that I had set up a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you're working with Firestore, you might encounter security issues that prevent you from writing data to the database. These issues are known as Firebase security rules. They're like the guardians of your data, making sure that only authorized users can access and modify it.

```
{
  "rules": {         
    "tariffs": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true && (!data.exists() || data.child('user').child('uid').val() === auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
```

And please look at the picture below to set the rules in Firestore.

[image]